# Do I need to vote for both reopen and undelete, or is just one sufficient?

Tags: support, closed-questions, voting, deleted-questions

A question was closed because it was a request for equipment. It was later deleted altogether. I edited the question to reframe it and then voted both to reopen and to undelete.

Were both votes needed, or does SE understand a vote for one as a vote for the other? If the latter, does voting for both create difficulties or confusion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to do both. Close/Reopen votes and delete/undelete votes are independent from each other and both need to be done.

As a side note I don't know the specific post, but deletion is not typically done lightly. Whether the OP deleted themselves, the post was auto deleted, or it was deleted for another reason, it may make more sense to write a new question rather than use an old one especially if it drastically changes the question.

Comment: The question is [Sustain Pedal with half-damper on Casio CDP135](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/87328/sustain-pedal-with-half-damper-on-casio-cdp135/104472#104472). It was deleted by the community user (does that mean auto deleted?).

Comment: @Aaron Yep it was auto deleted for the RemoveAbandonedClosed reason.